# Android: Best way to create a custom shaped Progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I would like to create a custom shaped progressbar, which would change color according to its progress (but this is almost a different question..).

So what would be the best way to create a custom shaped progressbar like the one on the image below (sorry for bad MS Paint drawing skills):

[image: custom shaped progressbar]

Comment: I was thinking of one "default" vertical progressbar and a custom shaped imageview on top of it (which would have a transparent space in form of this shape). But I think this isn´t the best way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have all possibilities you should create a custom class derived from progressbar and completely override the onDraw() Method. to draw the Arch on the side you can use `canvas.drawArc()` and to change the color of the bar you can simply adjust the Paint Color.

Comment: Could you maybe give me some sample code of the custom progressbar code?

Comment: I just created this: http://pastebin.com/pKhK3YCa It sould give you a little hint on what you have to override and use. The onDraw Method does nothing useful now. This is your Job :)

Comment: Thanks chuck! I think this will help!

Comment: @chuck258 i have tried you class it's crash while i run the application. what's the issue ?
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class com.example.rushabh_qs.guageprogressdemo.CustomBar