# Is there any way to customize a progressbar like this (start with a circle and then a rectangle body)

Tags: android, android-progressbar, shapes

I am working on an android app, which needs to show a custom progress bar like the image below. To customize a progress bar need to use  `android:progressDrawable`, so maybe need a drawable(self-defined shape). However, I don't know if is it possible using `shape` to do it?

[image]

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: You can write your custom view.

Comment: click progress-bar image, then you can see the image. Is there any tutorial about writing custom progressBar view?

Comment: I don't know, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357211/android-best-way-to-create-a-custom-shaped-progressbar, https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-draw-a-custom-view-9da8016fe94, http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/11/07/android-custom-progress-view/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646574/progress-bar-with-rounded-corners/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android. Also you can try to overlap transparent image mask over a purple rectangle. Probably you can see `RatingBar` code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `seekbar`. in `seekbar` widget you can change `android:progressDrawable` that means the rectangle area and also change `android:thumb` that means circle shape. But remeber you must implement custom seekbar that disabled user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using *FrameLayout* to overlay a progress bar and a circle imageView. It works perfectly.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/tagGoal_title_progressbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="10dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
               style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
               android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_color"
               android:progress="25"/>
           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/tagGoal_circle_progressbar"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="20dp"
               android:background="@drawable/bg_progress_circle"/>
</FrameLayout>
```